# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

Через Laravel Sail запускаю проект. Всё запускается. Делаю миграции через артизан - всё работает. Пытаюсь получить данные из БД через модель - User::all() - выдаёт -
`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `users`) `` .

Перечитал всё, что мог найти. Обычно предлагают сменить `DB_HOST=localhost`  на `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` или прописывать путь до сокета `DB_SOCKET=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` - не помогает.

php - 8;  mysql -8;  Linux - Ubuntu 20.04;

Полагаю, это что-то связанное с докером.